# Find running nodes form haproxy

Tags: linux, apache, haproxy

I have a haproxy load balancer (round robin) on server 192.168.1.10 and I have ten apache web server nodes in the back end. My server range is 192.168.1.20-30 from port 80. Is there a way to find the servers where services (httpd) are up and running from 192.168.1.10?

Comment: Are you looking to find which servers are currently healthy and being served from haproxy? Or are you looking for something dynamic that would populate haproxy.cfg automatically?

Comment: yes! i'm looking for simply what are the server are healthy and being served from haproxy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can access the status page and request it is returned in CSV format. To enable stats for haproxy use something like this in your haproxy.cfg (many options available but this is the most basic):

```
listen stats 192.168.1.10:8000
  stats uri /haproxy/stats
```

You then can access your status page via

```
http://192.168.1.10:8000/haproxy/stats
```

You can append ';csv' like so:

```
http://192.168.1.10:8000/haproxy/stats;csv
```

This will return all your backends and pool members in CSV format. It is trivial to parse this information to get the healthy httpd services.